# Protractor: HTTP Response Testing

Tags: json, node.js, protractor, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using [Protracotr](https://github.com/angular/protractor/) for e2e testing.

I want to test response from HTTP in protractor.
Basically:

1. I have running some NodeJS server.
2. I want to send request to this server
3. Receive some JSON data
4. Parse those data
5. Check if they are correct

I'm using "http" NODEJS Lib to make http calls GET+POST.

```
var http = require('http');

describe("Some test", function() {

    function httpGet(siteUrl) {
        http.get(siteUrl, function(response) {

            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            response.on("data", function(chunk) {
                bodyString += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {
                defer.fulfill({
                    bodyString: bodyString
                });
            });

        }).on('error', function(e) {
            defer.reject("Got http.get error: " + e.message);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

    it('Test case', function(){
        httpGet("http://localhost:3333/path/1/10").then(function(result) {
            var json_data = JSON.parse(result.bodyString);

            for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; ++i) {
                console.log("label: " + json_data[i].label);
                expect(json_data[i].label).toEqual('abc');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can see response message nice parsed in console.log, but I'm not able to test anything, my **test results are**:

```
Finished in 0.019 seconds
1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures

label: Text1
label: Text2

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**The console log is write down after finish of test and no assertion has been done.**

Any help please, how to test those responses (in JSON format) from server in Protractor?

Answer (score 2):

For async tests, you'll need to pass the done callback to your function. Then call `done()` on success or `done.fail()` on failure. See [Jasmine's Asynchronous support](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Asynchronous_Support) documentation.

```
it('Test case', function(done){
    httpGet("http://localhost:3333/path/1/10").then((result) => {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(result.bodyString);

        for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; ++i) {
            console.log("label: " + json_data[i].label);
        }
        done();
    }).catch(err => {
        done.fail();
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, I have some changes to your original question (under review). Your original question was about Protractor; however, I believe you are looking for Jasmine as the test framework.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am trying to call done() but that is not working, i am getting 'ReferenceError: done is not defined' error. And also: 'TypeError: httpGet(...).then(...).catch is not a function'

Comment: Yup. Good point... its because of the callback. You should use fat arrows. Let me update my answer.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure if we are both talking about same technology. I'm getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>". I'm using Protractor for testing Angular web pages via Web Driver. I'm working in JavaScript

Comment: I added little bit more information to my question (about protractor for e2e testing) and what test results I'm getting.

Comment: A quick search for a good post on fat arrows yields https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/. I would read up on "What about arguments" section. Also check your node version for ES6 support.